# Which of the following sets is/are countable/uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis

Which  of the following sets is/are countable/uncountable ?

$1)$The set of all infinite sequences of integers which are in arithmetic progression

$2)$The set of all infinite sequences of integers which are in geometric progression

$ 3)$The set of all infinite sequences of integers which are in Harmonic  progression

My  attempt : as I know  that $\mathbb{Z}$ is  countable but

I don't  know  how  to  determine  whether it is countable/uncounatble.

Please help me.

Comment: Start by writing down a handful of examples of arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Can you see that in every case, a sequence is defined by two integer-valued parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every arithmetic progression over the integers is determined by two numbers : a starting point and a common difference. Can you use this fact to demonstrate an injective map from the set of all arithmetic progressions of the integers, into $\mathbb Z^2$? Now, what do you know about $\mathbb Z^2$?

Can you think similarly for geometric series? For harmonic series, again a similar logic should apply : one may think of the arithmetric progressions created by the reciprocals. The starting point must be a rational. The difference of rationals is a rational, so the common difference is also a rational. What can you conclude now, knowing that the rationals are countable?